# ScrollIntoView() locks scroll Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular.  I have a component where I want the page to scroll down to the first error when the user attempts to save invalid inputs.  The code I am using is:

```
const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#input1');
            element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});
```

The page scrolls to the error just fine, but the problem is that it then **locks** the scroll.  Any attempt to scroll away from the error brings me right back to the same place, even if the error has been corrected.  How can I "release" the scroll once the page scrolls to the first error?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your code snipped is triggered again and again, maybe in an ngOnChange and that your error flag is never resolved?

Comment: That was it!  It was an ngDoCheck that was doing it.  Thank you!